# Daphne server command not available

Tags: django, channel, daphne

I have created a django app using channels, and tested it with `python3 manage.py runserver`, which, as I understand, runs a Daphne server as part of the command. Now I just want to deploy the app by running a standalone Daphne server with some workers, etc. following the [documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html). Problem is, I don't seem to have the `daphne` command available to me in the terminal. Running `daphne my_project.asgi:channel_layer` just results in my terminal telling me the daphne command isn't found. (Running Ubuntu 17.10, if it's at all relevant)

Daphne was definitely installed when I installed the channels package using pip. When I run `pip3 install daphne` it says that I have all the relevant packages and the installation is up-to-date. Am I doing something stupid here? Seems like this *just works* for everyone else. How can I get the daphne command available to me so I can start a server with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The fix was really easy; at first, I couldn't find the daphne install directory, but it was in `~/.local/bin`. You can either run daphne from that directory, or add the directory to the system `PATH` so that bash can run it directly.